# amp-call-tracking + amp-img sometime not showing

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I have set the amp-img on my mobile web to make the call as follow:

```
<p class="center">
    <amp-call-tracking config="https://www.onsumlock.com/calltracking.onsum">
    <a href="tel:97647811"><amp-img src="img/call.gif" width="300" height="107" alt="Lock1"></amp-img></a>
  </amp-call-tracking>

</p>
```

"https://www.onsumlock.com/calltracking.onsum"

```
{
    "phoneNumber": "97647811"

  }
```

I find the image (call.gif) some time can't display on phone, I think maybe the calltracking.onsum problem...
i don't know how to config, Please help me, Thank You!
http://www.onsumlock.com

Comment: I'm not sure if that's how amp-call-tracking should behave, but did you try asking or reporting this [issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amp-by-example/issues) to [ampproject GitHub](https://github.com/ampproject)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like amp-img is not supported inside amp-call-tracking. Please file a [new feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new) for amp-call-tracking.